# Create Back up image of the folder

Tags: 14.04, backup

Help me please what software(Ubuntu 14.04) to use for creating images (files, folder)
I have some folder and files (not OS) which I need to move to another HDD.
It should in one image file which i mount and copy some folders of files to new location.
ISO is not acceptable because overall size of the files is around 400Gigs?
Thank's for the answers.

Comment: ISO is not acceptable as you need compression, is that right?

Comment: no, I do not need compression

Answer (score 0):

**clonezilla** -> [about](http://clonezilla.org/)

Filesystem supported: (1) ext2, ext3, ext4, reiserfs, reiser4, xfs, jfs, btrfs of GNU/Linux, (2) FAT12, FAT16, FAT32, NTFS of MS Windows, (3) HFS+ of Mac OS, (4) UFS of FreeBSD, NetBSD, and OpenBSD, (5) minix of Minix, and (6) VMFS3 and VMFS5 of VMWare ESX. Therefore you can clone GNU/Linux, MS windows, Intel-based Mac OS, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Minix and VMWare ESX, no matter it's 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x86-64) OS. For these file systems, only used blocks in partition are saved and restored. For unsupported file system, sector-to-sector copy is done by dd in Clonezilla.

Comment: But I do not need to clone the whole partition. Something similar to Acronis Tib but on Ubuntu

Comment: if you can have both system online at the same time, i strongly suggest rsync